# Custom enumerate margin

Tags: enumerate, indentation

I would like to use the enumerate environment in such a way that all the text in the listed items is fully aligned to the left, in such a way that labels are aligned to the left, and aligned to the text in the the second line. I do not manage to find the right combination of optional parameters: if I align the text to the left by using leftmargin=0pt the labels appear inside the left margin (which I want to be left blank).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This the key `wide=0pt` of `enumitem`.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks, I must have read a million sites and did not find that :) Problem solved.

Comment: Th better is yet to take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\usepackage{enumitem}`to add many options to the three environments of list.

If you want a fully-left aligned list, you can use the options :

```
\documentclass[article]

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{enumerate}[wide]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
```

And if you don't want any indent on the item you can also use the options :
`labelindent=0pt` allows you to change the label indent.

You can find more information about the enumitem package [here](http://www.texnia.com/archive/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thanks for your help.